# How to create sub graph in ArangoDB?

Tags: graph-databases, arangodb, nosql

I am not able to find the way to create subgraph in arangodb.

no idea to found in the link https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/graphs/
how to create subgraph in arangodb ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Specifically, what do you mean by subgraph? Do you mean a graph that exists as a subset of the nodes and edges in another graph? If you're just reducing collections, you can do this fairly simply by creating a graph and defining only the node and edge collections you want to remain.

Comment: Yes exactly this is my requirement 'Do you mean a graph that exists as a subset of the nodes and edges in another graph?'. how to do this? because I have more number of collection in single graph.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the graph in the ArangoDB interface, you will be prompted to list all the node and edge collections. Simply choose the subset of node and edge collections you want. There are equivalent ways to do this via REST and ArangoSH, but ultimately it's the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a graph, it can contain many related vertex and edge collections. I have some graphs with 9 or more collections. You don't have to worry about creating a subgraph because ArangoDB will only use the collections that relate to your query.

So if you perform a query of all inbound connected vertices to a particular vertex you specify, ArangoDB will work out which edge and vertex collections to use to answer your query.

This is really powerful, as you don't have to track how collections are bound to each other in a 'graph space' rather just query it and the database handles it for you.

It is possible to reuse vertex and edge collections over multiple graphs, this can be useful if you want to reuse data in different groupings.

For me, I see graphs as another type of collection, which are really just a collection of connected vertex and edge collections. When you query the scope of that graph it uses it's graph definition to limit the scope of path traversals.